How do I tell the foreground program to send output to spool vs display?
I have a program that is running in foreground, with simple WRITE statements. When List Processing is complete, the program displays the contents of the output.  When I run this program in background, the output from the WRITE statements generates a spooled file.  I want to do the same when this program is running in foreground.
This is exception output that I need to log somewhere, but not on the display.
How do I code the output to go to spool for a program running in foreground?
I have not tried anything that I can describe here.  I do not want to create an ALV because the contents of the WRITE statements vary based on the data.

In general the NEW-PAGE PRINT ON statement can be used for this:
NEW-PAGE ABAP Help

I had tried that approach but really couldn't figure out that i needed to use PRI_PARAMS.  thank you for your prompt help.
